# Using Time.zone.now.to_date in instance or class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have the following code in a class method defined on the association. Will that value then get cached or is that just for the scopes?

```
def for_today
  where 'planned_for = ?', Time.zone.now
end
```

To clarify, if I do the below with a scope the Time.zone.now value will be the same as when the class was cached and I want to make sure this doesn't happen for the above or how to work around it.

```
scope :for_today, where('planned_for = ?', Time.zone.now)
```

So the correct way of writing a scope that is using a dynamic value would be to use a lambda like

```
scope :for_today, lambda { where('planned_for = ?', Time.zone.now) }
```

Do I need to do something similar for a class or instance method and if that is so what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that value will not get cached for class and instance methods, so you can safely use them.
As a rule of a thumb: for simple conditions use `scope`, and for more complex cases, use class methods.

Also, with default configuration, all times stored in database are in UTC, so you can just use Time.now since it will be auto-converted to UTC.

Comment: Thanks man one thing less to worry about though our database is stupidly enough storing dates as some US timezone. I am going to change that however. No reason to use anything except UTC for storage